# PHP setlocale() not working correctly on Windows 10 machine

Tags: php

I want to display a money amount in USD and I was looking for a function and found such in the PHP Manual - [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php). The one submited by Rafael M. Salvioni. It turned out that it was not working for some older OS so the setlocale() function should be used in order to prevent errors. So I had the following code:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

It was working fine on `Windows 8.1`, but now I'm using `Windows 10` and it seems that this is not working now. I have tried the following code to see what the setlocale functin will return:

```
<?php
 setlocale(LC_ALL,"US");
 $locale_info = localeconv();
 print_r($locale_info);
?>
```

And here is what I'm getting:

> Array ( [decimal_point] => . [thousands_sep] => [int_curr_symbol] => [currency_symbol] => [mon_decimal_point] => [mon_thousands_sep] => [positive_sign] => [negative_sign] => [int_frac_digits] => 127 [frac_digits] => 127 [p_cs_precedes] => 127 [p_sep_by_space] => 127 [n_cs_precedes] => 127 [n_sep_by_space] => 127 [p_sign_posn] => 127 [n_sign_posn] => 127 [grouping] => Array ( ) [mon_grouping] => Array ( ) )

The data seems to be pretty different when I run the same code in w3schools.com:

> Array ( [decimal_point] => . [thousands_sep] => , [int_curr_symbol] => USD [currency_symbol] => $ [mon_decimal_point] => . [mon_thousands_sep] => , [positive_sign] => [negative_sign] => - [int_frac_digits] => 2 [frac_digits] => 2 [p_cs_precedes] => 1 [p_sep_by_space] => 0 [n_cs_precedes] => 1 [n_sep_by_space] => 0 [p_sign_posn] => 3 [n_sign_posn] => 0 [grouping] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [mon_grouping] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) )

So I've manually set the values I needed for US:

```
$locale = array(
    'decimal_point'        => '.',
    'thousands_sep'        => ',',
    'int_curr_symbol'    => 'USD',
    'currency_symbol'    => '$',
    'mon_decimal_point'    => '.',
    'mon_thousands_sep'    => ',',
    'positive_sign'        => '',
    'negative_sign'     => '-',
    'int_frac_digits'    => 2,
    'frac_digits'        => 2,
    'p_cs_precedes'        => 1,
    'p_sep_by_space'    => 0,
    'p_sign_posn'        => 3,
    'n_sign_posn'        => 0,
    'grouping'            => array(),
    'mon_grouping'        => array(0 => 3, 1 => 3)
);
```

And it seems that this working now, however this solution will be working as long as I need the US currency.

Do you know why the setlocale() function is not working the same way in Windows 10 but it's working fine in Windows 8.1? I've been using the same PHP version both times.

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code gives me exactly the same result as what you are getting on Windows 10, and I just tested it on CentOS (Linux). Checking the return value of setlocale with var_dump tells me that it returns FALSE, and according to the PHP documentation it means:

> Returns FALSE if the locale functionality
>   is not implemented on your platform, the specified locale does not
>   exist or the category name is invalid.

So that leads me to making the following change, which gives the correct results you are after:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');
```

Comment: With the line above is it working on Linux or Windows? Because I have tried it on Windows and it was still not working correctly.